# Access VBA - OpenRecordset Saving Unwanted Old Data

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating a form in my Access 2010 Database to input employee users. The code also is used to edit existing users.

To avoid confusion - the **column names** I will be talking about (which exist in the table 'Employees') are `LastName` and `FirstName`, while the **input fields** on my form are `First` and `Last`.

The form I am creating is for insertion OR updating of employee data. When the user types into the `First` field, `Last` is auto-populated with a list of values from the `LastName` column where `FirstName = Me.First`. If the administrator selects a last name that was populated in the box (rather then typing one in themselves), than the existing record is opened for editing.

My SQL for the `Last` combobox

```
SELECT DISTINCT Last 
FROM [Employees] 
WHERE First = Forms![Employees]!First;
```

My Code for after the `Last` combox is updated (`Full` = "`LastName`, `FirstName`")::

```
Private Sub Last_AfterUpdate()
    Dim records As Recordset
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim db As Database

    Set db = CurrentDb

    If (DCount("Full", "Employees", "Full='" & Me.Last & "," & Me.First & "'") >= 1) Then
        tmp = Me.Last & "," & Me.First
        Set records = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * from [Employees] WHERE Full = '" & tmp & "'")
        Me.Recordset.FindFirst "ID1=" & records.Fields("ID1")
    End If

    If (DCount("Full", "Employees", "Full='" & Me.Last & ", " & Me.First & "'") >= 1) Then
        tmp = Me.Last & ", " & Me.First
        Set records = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * from [Employees] WHERE Full = '" & tmp & "'")
        Me.Recordset.FindFirst "ID1=" & records.Fields("ID1")
    End If
End Sub
```

**MY ISSUE:**

If an existing record is found, than the record is opened correctly. Before the record is opened, however, a new one is saved with the data the administrator has input thus far. This is the issue, I don't want the data saved, but I don't know exactly why it is occurring in the first place. Is there a way to stop the old record from saving, aside from deleting it programmatically?

Comment: Search controls need to be unbound. That is, their control sources should be empty. If they are not, then you tend to get this problem !